# Turn Off Automatic Trash Deletion?

Tags: wp-config, post-status, constants, trash

I have a client who wants to use the trash feature, but keep items in there indefinitely (I have no idea why, but they insist on it).

From reading [this codex article on the trash status](http://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status), I see that you can set the `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` constant to zero. But it says that this will disable trash functionality altogether. I don't want to do this. I just want to disable the *auto-trash emptying*.

Is there any way to do this? Or am I stuck with just entering some huge number for the `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is - yes, you are stuck with exactly that.

Checks for `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` seem to be hardcoded as condition for switching interface between trash and delete in several places.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Question though--I see that trash collection is scheduled as an event in wp-admin/admin.php (wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'wp_scheduled_delete');). Do you think it's possible to simply unschedule the event at some point? Maybe on every admin init? Or do you think that's just fighting against the system?

Comment: @MathSmath hmmm... I don't think it's worth it to fight with schedule (schedules are persistent = messy db reads/writes), but you can try to remove `wp_scheduled_delete()` function from `wp_scheduled_delete` hook. I am not sure about at what hook/stage it would be best for that in cron environment.

Answer (score 22):

You can do the following:

- Set `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` to a very high number. E.g.: `define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 1000000 );`
- Or remove the `wp_schedule_delete` action:

  ```
  function my_remove_schedule_delete() {
      remove_action( 'wp_scheduled_delete', 'wp_scheduled_delete' );
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'my_remove_schedule_delete' );
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I actually worked it out with Rarst just a few minutes before you posted. I'm giving you a vote and Rarst the answer. Thanks again!